# how configure strophe ejabbber by access on lan

Tags: cors, web-config, ejabberd, strophe

Error on my ip local>

```
POST http://localhost.server.com/bosh 404 (Not Found)
sendFunc    @   strophe.js:5662
_processRequest @   strophe.js:5677
_throttledRequestHandler    @   strophe.js:5823
_connect    @   strophe.js:5170
connect @   strophe.js:3051
(anonymous) @   Jchat.js:438
handle  @   jquery.js:2693
(anonymous) @   jquery.js:2468
trigger @   jquery.js:2641
(anonymous) @   jquery.js:2919
each    @   jquery.js:692
each    @   jquery.js:155
trigger @   jquery.js:2918
Connect @   Jchat.js:271
(anonymous) @   jquery-ui.js:7387
handle  @   jquery.js:2693
(anonymous) @   jquery.js:2468
```

external accesss>

I want to access the link of one  application in internet information services(IIS) in a local network but when I want to access it, I get this error

```
Failed to load http://localhost.server.com/bosh: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I used this code

https://jasonrowe.com/2011/11/18/strophejs-ejabberd-iis-setup/

Comment: There actual error you’re getting is a 404 for an OPTIONS request to `http://localhost.server.com/bosh`. Sounds like you need to figure out how to make  the server respond correctly to OPTIONS requests. It’s not now

Comment: ok, i will make configurations server, but other error possible...

Answer (score 0):

the error is connect to client bosh you have to aim a your local ip before you have add in file host you ip and domain. And write rules urlrewrite on iis

example:

```
192.168.0.1  localhost.server.com
```

and

```
BOSH_DOMAIN = "http://192.168.0.1:5280/http-bind"
```